# How do I delete an iCloud backup?

Tags: backup, icloud, ipad

I just got a new iPad2 (upgraded from an iPad1) today and I was going to do an iCloud backup, but it says there is no more data for me to use.

I want to either download all the data from my original iPad onto my new iPad and then delete the old iCloud backup, but I can't find anywhere to do that. The cloud is recognizing the devices seperatly. I can't even just delete the iPad1 backup to do a brand new backup, the system (on my iPad2, iPhone and Mac) all say "Could not delete this backup at this time, try again later"...

Is this even possible to download my iPad1 backup onto my iPad2?

Comment: Are you using the same Apple ID?

Comment: Yep. I can access the backup in the iCloud area of settings on both my ipad2, iphone and mac, but I can't delete or download from the ipad1 backup. I also don't have access to my ipad1 anymore.

Comment: Having the same problem... can delete old info from icloud.... how did you solve this?

Comment: @Ana It was apparently something that had to do with Apple's servers. A few days later I was able to delete the backup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Tap Settings and then tap the iCloud icon.
2. Tap "Storage & Backup."
3. Tap Manage Storage.
4. Tap your iOS device in the Backups area.
5. Under Backup Options, turn off any items that you no longer wish to back up.
6. Return to Storage & Backup and tap “Back up now.” This will immediately remove the requested backup data from iCloud.
7. Choose “Delete Backup” if you want to turn off Backup and remove all data for that Backup from iCloud.

(via [support.apple.com](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4847))

Comment: I checked Apple's documentation, but it still won't delete the old backup.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @gentmatt's answer, if you're backup won't delete, it could be because of a restore-block. I found this by speaking with a senior apple advisor on the phone:

> Once an iCloud backup restore has been activated for a device, a
>   restore-block is placed on the backup for 48 hours. During this time,
>   the backup cannot be deleted.